# sql database convention

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller, convention

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question. I've more or less just started learning how to use SQL.

I'm making a website, the website stores main accounts, each having many sub-accounts associated with them. Each sub-account has a few thousand records in various tables associated with it.

My question is to do with the conventional usage of databases. Is it better to use a database per main account with everything associated with it stored in the same place, store everything in one database, or an amalgamation of both?

Some insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you need to access more than one of these databases at the same time? If so put them all in one. You will not like the amount of effort and cost 'joining' them back together to do a query. On top of that, every database you have needs to be managed, and should you need to transfer data between them that can get painful as well.

Segregating data by database is a last resort.